# Как правильно записать динамический метод в классе?

Tags: php

Имеется класс с множеством методов

```
$method = getName();
ClassName::$method
```

`$method` должен подставляться автоматически, но при попытке это сделать я получаю сообщение об ошибке

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: ClassName::$method in

Возможно так писать код нельзя, но если есть возможность, то помогите решить эту задачу.

Comment: `$method = 'getName';  ClassName::$method()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написано, что нельзя обратитсья к необъявленному статическому **свойству** (это можно узнать просто скопировав текст в переводчик).

А метод вызывается круглыми скобками.

Comment: Благодарю за подсказку.